# Magento: Adding custom field to Newsletter using Observers

Tags: php, magento

First... I'm new to this so bear with me.

I'm trying to make a module which adds custom field to newsletter using observers.

I made a column in "newsletter_subscribers" table (mysql4-install-0.1.0.php)

```
$installer = $this;
$installer->startSetup();

$installer->run("
  ALTER TABLE {$this->getTable('newsletter_subscriber')}
    ADD (user_name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL);
 ");

$installer->endSetup();
```

Then i modified config.xml for observer

```
<events>
   <newsletter_subscriber_save_before>
      <observers>
         <My_Newsletter>
            <type>model</type>
            <class>Newsletter_Observer</class>
            <method>newsletterSubscriberSaveBefore</method>
         </My_Newsletter>
      </observers>
   </newsletter_subscriber_save_before>
</events>
```

Then made an observer.php

```
class My_Newsletter_Model_Observer
{
    public function newsletterSubscriberSaveBefore(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
    {
        $subscriber = $observer->getEvent()->getSubscriber();
        $name = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam('subscriber_name');

        $subscriber->setSubscriberName($name);

        return $this;
    }
}
```

So my questions is.
What did i miss?
It doesn't work. I know I'm missing something important.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You specify
    `ADD (user_name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL);`

That means your code should be:

```
 $subscriber->setUserName($name);
```

Comment: Nothing stupid about your question.  Do the steps that @mischa-leiss laid out and it will answer that question.

Answer (score 0):

well easiest solution to explain would be to put a

```
die("TEST");
```

at the beginning of the method itself.
If it dies with output TEST the observer is listening to the dispatched event.

1. Clear the cache, because Magento doesnt know due to ddl caching, even if caching is off in admin menu.
2. Have you taken a look at `'newsletter_subscriber'` table? Did the sql script do its job?
3. According to @SeanBreeden you need to call your magic setter-method via `setUserName($name);`
4. Is your observer in the right section if saved from frontend (`<global> or <frontend>`)?

Comment: short atswer, it didn't work. 1. cleared cache one more time. 2. sql is working, there is a new column in db. 3. well there's "die" so it doesn't get there now. :D . 4. it's in <global> (but doesn't work in frontend eather). thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys. It was my fault atfer all. I put "Newsletter_Observer" class in config.xml, but my Observer.php was in Newsletter/Model/ folder.